# Remove certain letters in foma

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a rule to remove the non-start `[a | e | h | i | o | u | w | y]` letters in a string. The rule should keep the first letter, but remove given letters in other locations.

For example,

```
vave -> vv
aeiou -> a
```

My code is as below:

```
?* [ a | e | h | i | o | u | w | y ]+:0 ?* [ a | e | h | i | o | u | w | y ]+:0;
```

However, when applying the rule on `vaavaa`, it returns

```
vaav
vava
vava
vav
vava
vava
vav
vvaa
vva
vva
vv
```

while `vv` is what I want.

Please share some advice. Thanks!

Comment: It takes more than just a regex to do this.  Show us the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex for search:

```
(?!^)[aehiouwy]+
```

and replace it by emptry string `""`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GYVkaO/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?!^)`: Lookahead to make sure it is not at start
- `[aehiouwy]+`: Match one or more of these letters inside `[...]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a captured group and alternation

```
^(.)|[aehiouwy]+
```

[image]

replace by `\1`

[`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/1Vab16/2/)

Comment: @sealpuppy `()` is captured group, it stores reference to matched values. which can be referenced back by using backreferece. [`Ref`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)